# Migrating gems into RVM that were installed prior to installing RVM

Tags: ruby, import, rvm

I have an incredibly disorganized collection of Ruby libraries throughout my computer so I finally installed RVM to get things under control - Is there any way to import my past gem installations into RVM or do I need to re-download all previously installed gems?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for installing rvm (tears in my eyes)

Comment: Are the Ruby libraries you are mentioning all gems?

Comment: I'm as new as they come, learning from mistakes along the way. I can't even keep track of where my Ruby libraries are at this point.

Comment: For the most part..what would my other options be? I presume they are a collection of different ruby versions, associated libraries, and installed gems.

Comment: My main problem is now I can't use 'require' properly because RVM won't find those gems installed to system Ruby, but I don't want to have to search for exactly what I'm missing and then reinstall everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
rvm use system
rvm gemset export Gemfile
rvm use ruby-version
bundle install
```

You can edit the `Gemfile` and customize it to your needs (like remove versions)